# Macbook Notes app can't access data

Tags: notes.app, data-recovery, data

I was using the notes app just fine when I closed and reopened it to a pop-up message saying that it couldn't access my data. I tried reopening the app several times and restarting my computer. The message no longer shows up and just shows a blank version of the app. I can't make new notes or view my old ones. Is there a way to get my old notes back?

Answer (score 0):

I give this as answer, because the command can't be given in comment mode :

You can begin by repair your user autorisations with terminal command  :

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

Comment: RE: "I give this as answer, because the command can't be given in comment mode :" --  You can give this _shell commands_ in a comment, just like this: `diskutil resetUserPermissions /  $(id -u)`